# Azure function powershell script, how to implement multiple helper functions in the same Azure function?

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, helper

I created an Azure Function. In this function I would like to implement some helper functions.  I dont want to import modules, but would like to add the helper functions inside the function. How can I implement this?

For example

```
using namespace System.Net

function HelperFunctionCreateTab {param([string] $tabName, [string] $channelName)
    // some helper function logic
}

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
        
   Write-Output "START"
    
   // some main function logic

   HelperFunctionCreateTab -tabName "tabX" -channelName "channelY"

   // some main function logic
    
   Write-Output "START"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intent to implement the helper function in the same azure function then you need to add it after `param` block.

**`param`** block needs to be at the top, after **`using`** block in your function or else you will get input binding error.

I am using below code to implement the helper function.

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

function HelperFunctionCreateTab {
    param([string] $tabName, [string] $channelName)
    
    # Helper function logic
    Write-Output "Creating tab '$tabName' in channel '$channelName'"
}

Write-Output "START"

# Call the helper function
HelperFunctionCreateTab -tabName $Request.Query.tabName -channelName $Request.Query.channelName

Write-Output "END"

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = "Function execution completed."
})
```

**Output**-

[image]